# Retorno "Undefined" Ajax PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Seguinte estou tentando retornar um valor do banco de dados via Ajax.

Ao clicar no botão:

```
<button id="btn-database-finder" name="database-link" type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-xs btn-to-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#databaseModal">Visualizar</button>
```

Ele vai para o Ajax:

```
$("#btn-database-finder").on("click",function(){
    var radioid = $('#id-viewer').html();   
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"../connect/post/select.php",
        data:'database-link='+radioid,
        success:function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR, data){
            $("#database-viewer").html('<a href=../dashboard/dist/archives/databases/'+data+'><i  class="fa fa-file-archive-o fa-5x" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></a>'); 

         }      
      });

});
```

Que pega esta linha:

```
<i class="fa fa-hashtag" id="id-viewer" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Onde está o *ID* entro da TAG **li**.

Nesta parte está tudo funcionando, colocando um **alert()** aparece o *ID*, mas quando ele vai para o  `url:"../connect/post/select.php",`

Que é:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){ 


       $stDatabase = $_POST['database-link'];           
       $sendDatabase = $selDatabase->selectDatabase($stDatabase);


        exit();
}
```

Ele sempre retorna o como undefined:

```
<a href="dashboard/dist/archives/databases/undefined"><i class="fa fa-file-archive-o fa-5x" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: pointer;"></i></a>
```

Comment: De acordo com a [api](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), há somente 3 parâmetros em `success`: `data`, `textStatus` e `jqXHR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O JavaScript não recebe nada porque está faltando "imprimir" a resposta na saída do PHP. Coloquei um exemplo pra melhorar, enviando *headers* para identificar a resposta como JSON:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){ 


       $stDatabase = $_POST['database-link'];           
       $sendDatabase = $selDatabase->selectDatabase($stDatabase);

       // Envia headers com content-type adequado
       header( 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' );
       // Imprime o resultado como se fosse mostrar na tela
       echo json_encode($sendDatabase);
       exit();
}
```

Comment: Agora ele está voltando como `object`.

Comment: @WagnerViana na resposta do javascript, antes do `$("#database-viewer").html`, coloque `console.log(responseData)` e cola aqui o que aparece no console.

Comment: Opa arruei uma coisa e agora aparece Object {RadioDatabase: "581b122242703.rar"}

Comment: Isso parece mais próximo do resultado. Troque `/'+data+'` por `/'+responseData.RadioDatabase+'` na resposta do javascript e deve funcionar.